# Free dynamic array of static arrays?

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic-arrays

I have code similar to this

*EDIT* this code is supposed to be on interface so only POD is allowed. No vectors, no containers.

```
int (*neco)[2];

int ahoj = 2;
neco = new int[ahoj+2][2];
int iter = 1;
for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for (size_t j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        neco[i][j] =iter;
        iter++;
    }

}

for (size_t i = 0; i < ahoj + 2; i++)
{
    delete[] neco[i];
}
```

This does not work. The delete deletes memory not allocated.
Not even

delete[] neco;

Or any other delete. Everyone of them deletes memory BEFORE the allocated block.

Googling and consulting with peers in the office had no results. :)

How do I allocate dynamic array of "points" (two coordinates) and then free them?

I am able to solve the problem via using different structure.

But apperently I am able to allocate the memory. Write in the allocated memory…

How do I correctly free this memory? (Just accademic question.)

Comment: `std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>`

Comment: Did you try `delete [] neco;` without a loop? There's only one `new`, so there should be only one `delete`.

Comment: @user463035818 Oh I wish I could use that. :) But as the code is part of the interface, only POD is to be used.

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes, we tried that. It was the first we tried. And it was the start point of our search. The delete[] deleted memory before the allocated block.

Comment: @Kapitan Then your problem most likely lies somewhere else, but is exposed by this deallocation. Without a [mcve], there's nothing much anyone can add.

Comment: @Kapitan molbdnilo is entirely correct. After fixing that loop (aka, removing it and just using a single `delete[]`, valgrind will report no errors or leaks. I suggest you run a memory checker over your application, because odds are you're blowing up your own heap.

Comment: the extra memory might be related to some debug build, for instance [Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/crt-debug-heap-details?view=vs-2017): _[..]In a Debug build, however, malloc would call _malloc_dbg, which would then call the base heap allocation routine requesting an allocation of 10 bytes plus approximately 36 bytes of additional memory [..]_

Answer (score 1):

Plain pointers to dynamically allocated memory get you into troubles.

Use a [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr):

```
#include <memory>
// ...
std::unique_ptr<int[][2]> neco(new int[ahoj+2][2]);
```

And remove that loop with `delete[]`.

Alternatively, use `std::vector<int[2]> neco(ahoj+2)` - it does memory management for you and can be resized.

Answer (score 1):

The general rule is that every `new` expression must be matched by a single corresponding `delete` expression.

Your `new` expression is the right hand side of the statement

```
neco = new int[ahoj+2][2];
```

so the corresponding `delete` expression is given in the statement

```
delete [] neco;
```

If that doesn't work (which is what you claim) it means the problem is in some other code exhibiting undefined behaviour.

Your loop

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < ahoj + 2; i++)
{
    delete[] neco[i];
}
```

is incorrect because none of the `neco[i]` are the result of a `new` expression.  So `delete [] neco[i]` has undefined behaviourin every loop iteration.

Given that your code sample(s) and description are incomplete, I doubt anyone else can give more useful advice.

Also, you are mistaken in your belief that you can't use a standard container.  You can.

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
     std::vector<int[2]> avec(ahoj + 2);     
     int (*neco)[2] = &avec[0];

     for (size_t i = 0; i < ahoj + 2; ++i)
     {
         for (size_t j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
         {
             neco[i][j] = iter;
             ++iter;
         }
     }
}
```

The only difference is that `avec` does the dynamic memory allocation and deallocation for you.  `neco` is still a pointer to an array as required (according to your description) by your API.     The two constraints on this approach are;

- don't resize the`avec` after initialising `neco`   (or reinitialise `neco` whenever `avec` is resized)
- don't use `neco` after `avec` ceases to exist (since the behaviour will then be undefined).

Also, none of the arrays are actually static.   So your question is mistitled.

Answer (score 0):

If I can recall properly, an array of arrays (being dynamic or static), is basicly a matrix.

So, the academic answer:

The same way you allocate memory (first allocate the memory of the array of arrays, then with a `for`you allocate the memory of the arrays inside the array), to free it, you need to delete in a `for`the memory of the arrays, and then, in a simple `delete`, free the memory of the dynamic array.

So:

`arrayOfArrays[[array1][array2][array3][array4]]`

means: allocate memory of `arrayOfArrays`, then in a loop, allocate memory of `array(number)`

Same goes the other way around.

Free memory of `arrayOfArrays`in a single sentence.